# Getting undefined is not an object

Tags: json, react-native

I am looking for sample project of React-Native. First of all i got erro which is unable to resolve router flux. Then i added flux dependency and i run npm start. After that i got "Undefined is not an object" in package.json. How can i solve it. Can you please help me?

```
{
 "name": "FirsTrial",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
 "test": "jest"
},
 "dependencies": {
 "react": "16.3.1",
 "react-native": "0.55.3",
 "react-native-router-flux": "3.38.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "22.4.3",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
"jest": "22.4.3",
"react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
 "jest": {
 "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

"FirsTrial" is underlined !!!

Comment: did you run npm install after adding in package.json?

Comment: Yes. but same problem occurs.